# Is there a way to protect logged in contents in Flask without using flask-login to manage users?

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I am trying to set up a POC website in Flask\python to play around with some APIs. I have made a simple login page that redirects to /loggedin. But /loggedin is also accesible by just writing https://mysite/loggedin.html. Is there an easy way to prevent this that does not involve using something like flask-login? I don't want to spend time setting up an SQL user base and such, as I will be the only user of the application.

```
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
    def home():
return render_template("home.html")

@app.route("/loggedin")
    def innsiden():
return render_template("loggedin.html")

@app.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def login():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['username'] != 'admin' or request.form['password'] != 'admin':
            error = 'Invalid Credentials. Please try again.'
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('loggedin'))
    return render_template('login.html', error=error)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In flask you can maintain on the server "session" information. 
A simple method might be to

1. When user logs in with the correct password, add their username to the session data
2. When a logged in user visits a "secure" page, flask checks to see if their user id is in the sesson data `if 'username' in session:`. If it is, they are directed to the correct page, if not they are directed to a log in page
3. When the user logs out, their user name is removed from the list.

A version of this recipe is described at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_sessions.htm